# Issues with depricated functions in tensor flow 2.0.0-alpha0 release

Tags: tensorflow

As everyone know the new version of tensor flow is available now. And they provide a tool to upgrade your code easily using `tf_upgrade_v2 --infile original_code.py --outfile upgraded_code.py`. And after upgrading the code it will produce a `txt report` to inform you about all the changes has been made beside the issues that need some special attentions i.e the functions which are already deprecated and there is no further replacement for them.

So unfortunately my code has several of deprecated functions and I am looking for replacements for it but still not succeed in that. If any one can suggest to me any replacement to it I will be grateful.

1-

```
 L1 = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('L1', shape=[feature_dim, feature_dim],
                            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(wd), use_resource=False)
```

So the xavier_initializer and l2_regularizer are both deprecated.

2- `image = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, angles=rnd_rot_angle)`

3- `transform = tf.contrib.image.matrices_to_flat_transforms(tf.linalg.inv(afine_tf.params))`

4- `image = tf.contrib.image.transform(image, transform)`

5- python logging function doesn't show any logs on the terminal anymore.

```
import tenosflow
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('It doens't print this')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regularizers and initializers you can use `tf.keras.regularizers.l2` and `tf.initializers.GlorotNormal`(or GlorotUniform) respectfully. The latter is essentially the other name for Xavier initialization. 
As for contrib module, it is removed completely from TF 2.0 and many functions, at least for now, have no direct replacement. But you can use `tf.py_function` inside your input pipeline. It can wrap any piece of python logic as TensorFlow op.

```py
def custom_resize(image):
    return np.resize(image, (100,100))

def parse_func(image, label):
    return tf.py_function(custom_resize, inp=[image], Tout=[tf.float32])
...
dataset = dataset.map(parse_func)
```

So basically we can define any function, that will accept numpy arrays, not tensors and apply it to any tensor in dataset.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It seems this is what I need. It help a lot. Just one more thing, regarding the initializer and regularizer I tried that before posting this post but it dose't work. May be because the tf.compat.v1.get_variable is not the same as tf.contrib.get_variable()? Do you have any thoughts on this.

Comment: Good question! Seems like it only accepts `tf.compat.v1.initializers`, which doesn't have glorot. But Glorot is used by default. It's mentioned here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26665

Comment: Thanks, there is really problem in renaming the initializer as the raised issue you mentioned. However, I still have a  problem with the regularizers.  I will search more and find out what should I used.

Comment: it should work, `regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(value)`

Comment: It seems the error thrown was triggered by only the initializer. Thank you a lot .Yes it works.

Comment: and just one thing, the `tf.compat.v1.initilizers` have actually the glorot_normal. so now it is like this `L1 = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('L1', shape=[32, 32],
   ...:                             initializer=tf.compat.v1.initializers.glorot_normal() , regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.005), use_resource=False)
   ...: 
`

Comment: I added another issue (5). I am trying to find the problem and solution for it.

Comment: logging isn't included in TF2, as in other cases, use tf.compat.v1.logging. see https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180827-api-names.md

Comment: But I am not using tf.logging and I know this one is deprecated . I was using python logging function. If I used it without importing tensorflow it will work. But it will not work with tensorflow. And in the documentation you provided they said ` Python logging module can be used instead.`

Comment: tf.compat.v1.logging should work. `tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO)`. As for number 6, I'd advise to ask new question. It's not a good practice to post several questions as one, besides, it also requires some code as context

Comment: I did realize that the summay issue has lots of problem as I am investigating the issue. I deleted the issue(6). And I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769845/resourcesummarywriter-object-has-no-attribute-add-summary-with-tensorflow-2-0